Separate Boost async read and async write in two threads
I was looking at the documentation provided by Boost regarding how to realize TCP async client/server (echo server, chat, and so on), but I didn't find anything related to managing the async read and async write using two different threads.
In my scenario, I have a client that gets async messages from the server and sends these to a method that manages and produces data that will be sent to a server, but the "send message" phase to the server is not dependent from the operation before, but it happens at a periodic time (it could happen, for example, that the client sends to the server old data because the server didn't send updated data).
I need a suggestion about this problem. My idea was to split the async read and async write operations into operations managed by two different threads (in this way, the sending phase can be executed at a fixed time) and maybe a third one that manages the phase of manipulating data before sending to server (of course, I'll need to synchronize the exchange of information between the thread that produces information and the method that manages the information in order to produce data that will be sent to the server).

You should increase an amount of threads that execute io_context::run() to at least 2, so you can continue sending while at the same time handle incoming messages

Please read [ask]. Point is, I can't imagine what an answer here would even look like or even what criteria you seem to apply to a prospective answer. If you have working code and you want someone to take it apart, consider codereview.stackexchange.com instead. Do make sure to first read their site guidelines though!

@UlrichEckhardt I was just asking for suggestion around the approach to use.

@DmytroOvdiienko with async operations there's absolutely no need for multiple threads to achieve precisely that

@sehe If you are running 1 thread you cannot process the incoming data and at the same time send the rest of the data queued for sending.

That's simply incorrect. The definition of asynchronous IO is concurrency without threads. See also my answer which demonstrates it with code

Forgot to mention you, @DmytroOvdiienko

@sehe Whatever you may think about AsyncIO, in case if there are two items in the I/O completion port (Windows) or epoll (Linux) if you are running 1 thread, you cannot process those two items simultaneously. So if you are handling the incoming data and socket became writable, you cannot initiate the next write operation until the received bytes are processed.

@DmytroOvdiienko well that's confusing the IO with the processing. The processing is obviously just your regular application logic, and if you need threads to scale that, that has little to do with IO. Good thing that my answer code already perfectly lends itself for use from multiple threads, as explained. The need for threads doesn't arise from the need for concurrent read and write operations though.

Threading is not required for this at all:
struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    Session(tcp::socket socket) : socket(std::move(socket)) {}

    void start() {
        asio::post(socket.get_executor(), [this, self = shared_from_this()] { do_read_loop(); });
    }

    void write(std::string msg) {
        asio::post(socket.get_executor(), [this, msg = std::move(msg)]() mutable {
            write_msgs.push_back(std::move(msg));
            if (write_msgs.size() == 1) {
                do_write_loop();
            }
        });
    }

  private:
    // all privates are on the strand
    void do_read_loop() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket.async_read_some( //
            asio::buffer(data), [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                std::cout << "Received (" << ec.message() << ") " << quoted(std::string(data.data(), length))
                          << std::endl;
                if (!ec) {
                    do_read_loop();
                }
            });
    }

    void do_write_loop() {
        if (write_msgs.empty())
            return;

        asio::async_write(socket, asio::buffer(write_msgs.front()),
            [this, self=shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/) {
                if (!ec) {
                    write_msgs.pop_front();
                    do_write_loop();
                }
            });
    }

    tcp::socket socket;
    std::array<char, 1000> data;
    std::deque<std::string> write_msgs;
};

Now, no matter whether you run this on a single thread or e.g. using asio::threadpool with a strand for the socket executor, everything will work correctly.
